# docker nginx container not receiving request from outside, connection refused

Tags: nginx, docker, request, port

I have a running nginx container: `# docker run --name mynginx1 -P -d nginx`;

And got its PORT info by `docker ps`:  `0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->443/tcp`

Then I could get response from within the container(id: c30991a04b2f):

- `docker exec -i -t c3099 bash`
- `curl http://localhost` => which return the default `index.html` page content, it works

However, when I make the `curl http://localhost:32769` outside of the container, I got this:

`curl: (7) failed to connect to localhost port 32769: Connection refused`

---

I am running on a mac with docker version 1.9.0;  nginx latest

Does anyone know what cause this? Any help? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are On OSX, you are probably using a VirtualBox VM for your docker environment.

Make sure you have [forwarded your port 32769](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md#port-forwarding) to your actual host (the mac), in order for that port to be visible from localhost.
This is valid for the old boot2docker, or the new docker machine.

```
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port32769  ,tcp,,32769,,32769"
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "udp-port32769 ,udp,,32769,,$32769
```

(`controlvm` if the VM is running, `modifyvm` is the VM is stopped)
(replace "`boot2docker-vm`" b ythe name of your vm: see `docker-machine ls`)

I would recommend to not use `-P`, but a static port mapping `-p xxx:80 -p yyy:443`.
That way, you can do that port forwarding once, using fixed values.

Of course, you can access the VM directly through `docker-machine ip vmname`

```
curl http://$(docker-machine ip vmname):32769
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps.! I also read that on another post just now. I just started learning docker, still  got a lots of docs to go through.

Answer (score 2):

Solved..  I misunderstood how docker port mapping works.
Since I'm using mac, the host for nginx container is a VM, `0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp` maps the port `80` of the container to the port `32769` of the VM.

---

solution:

1. `docker-machine ip vm-name` => `192.168.99.xx`
2. `curl http://192.168.99.xx:32769`

Comment: Also, you can run "docker-machine ls" to see the IP of your 'default'.  For example, the VM IP in this case is 192.168.99.100:
> docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly answers for your question but spend some time trying to figure out similar thing in context of "why is my docker container not connecting to elastic search `localhost:9200`" and this was the first S.O. question that pops up, so I hope it helps some other googling person

if you are `link`ing  containers together (e.g. `docker run --rm --name web2 --link db:db training/webapp env`)

... then Dockers adds enviroment variables:

`DB_NAME=/web2/db
    DB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
    DB_PORT_5432_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
    DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO=tcp
    DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
    DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.5`

... and also updates your `/etc/hosts`

```
# /etc/hosts
#...
172.17.0.9  db
```

so you can technically connect to `ping db`

https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/

so for elastic search is

```
 # /etc/hosts
 # ...
 172.17.0.28    elasticsearch f9db83d0dfb5 ecs-awseb-qa-3Pobblecom-env-f7yq6jhmpm-10-elasticsearch-fcbfe5e2b685d0984a00
```

so `wget elasticseach:9200` will work