# Docker won't publish selected ports

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I've created a container running ElasticSearch on Docker (9200 and 9300 are published so they can be accessed via the host).

```
$ docker run --name books-es -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -d elasticsearch
65937a0f8967390d33abaad50b55975cb9292be6692d29791c2e6c37ac5d2832
```

I then test to see if it's running:

```
$ docker exec books-es curl 127.0.0.1:9200
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   315{   0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  "name" : "Masque",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.0.0",
    "build_hash" : "de54438d6af8f9340d50c5c786151783ce7d6be5",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-10-22T08:09:48Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.2.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
  100   315    0     0   5204      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5625
```

I identify the ip of my docker.

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

But when testing the server from here, no response.

```
$ curl 192.168.99.100:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 9200: Connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that ElasticSearch listens on ip `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`.
Since `docker exec books-es curl 127.0.0.1:9200` works, this seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to map explicit port `192.168.99.100:9200:9200`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the right environment variable:

```
eval $(docker-machine ip default)
```

And if that is not working, try with:

- [port mapping at the VM level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707882/6309)

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port9200,tcp,,9200,,9200"
  VBoxManage controlvm "default" --natpf1 "udp-port9200,udp,,9200,,9200"
  ```
- `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`