# How to connect mysql workbench to running mysql inside docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql server inside docker container and able to access inside docker. How to create connection in mysql workbench running on my local(Host Machine).

Comment: I was having problems connecting to the mysql on the container from mysql workbench, and the problem was that currently mysql workbench is incompatible with the latest versions of mysql, namely 8.1. Therefore, using an older version of mysql image, 8.0.34 in my case, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 102):

By default after deployment MySQL has following connection restrictions:

```
mysql> select host, user from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| localhost | healthchecker |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
+-----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Apparently, for security purposes, you will not be able to connect to it from outside of the docker container.
If you need to change that to allow root to connect from any host (say, for development purposes), do the following:

1. Start your mysql image with all port mappings required:

   `docker run -p 3306:3306 --name=mysql57 -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7`

or, if the complete port mapping is required:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 --name=mysql57 -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

2. If this is the fresh installation - grab the default password:

   `docker logs mysql57 2>&1 | grep GENERATED`
3. Connect using `mysql` client directly to the mysqld in docker:

   `docker exec -it mysql57 mysql -uroot -p`
4. If this is a fresh installation you will be asked to change the password using `ALTER USER` command. Do it.
5. Run SQL:

   `update mysql.user set host = '%' where user='root';`
6. Quit the `mysql` client.
7. Restart the container:

   `docker restart mysql57`

Now you will be able to connect from MySQL Workbench to

```
host: `0.0.0.0` 
port: `3306`
```

After all the changes the query will show:

```
select host, user from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| %         | root          |
| localhost | healthchecker |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: thank you, this answer helped me a lot. Only changing the password was not documente here, found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511149/8439926

Comment: Thank U Andrey, today I was having this problem, I already had about 3 days trying to connect, and I just used the ip 0.0.0.0 and port 3306 from your tip and it worked, but I use mysqlsh.

Comment: In my experienced ignorance I never thought `0.0.0.0` would be correct ... but it was !

Comment: Thanks Andrey, this allowing '%' access just slipped my mind.

Comment: When I run other applications in docker, only providing my ipv4 addess instead of localhost allows me to connect. Right now I am not able to connect to mysql:latest docker container using  workbench. Is that because of this connection restriction or my own error?

Comment: Sorry, @MurtazaHaji , I don't know what is the cause of your problem connecting to the `mysql:latest`. Could be a number of things, including network issues.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Very helpful.

Comment: How can we confirm that `0.0.0.0` is actually tied to `%` for `root`?

Answer (score 59):

You have to do few configuration in you docker container. Please follow the following steps.

1. Specify mysql configuration block in your docker-compose.yml. I have following mysql block under **services** object in my docker-compose.yml file.

   ```
   services:
       db:
           image: mysql
           volumes:
               - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
           environment:
               MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
               MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
               MYSQL_USER: user
               MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
           ports:
               42333:3306
   ```
2. Restart docker container and run following commands to get to the bash shell in the mysql container

   ```
   docker ps
   docker exec -it <mysql container name> /bin/bash
   ```

   Inside the container, to connect to mysql command line type,

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   Use **MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD** as specified in the docker-compose.yml . Execute following commands to create new user.

   ```
   create user 'user'@'%' identified by 'pass';
   grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'%' with grant option;
   flush privileges;
   ```

   The percent sign (%) means all ip's. Restart the docker container.
3. In your MySQL Workbench provide the connection details. Use **MYSQL_PASSWORD** as specified in your docker-compose.yml file.

   [image]

You should now be able to connect to your mysql container.

Comment: Where did you get this IP from?

Comment: The IP shown above is my vagrant box IP address. In your case you can find it in Vagrantfile in your vagrant folder.

Comment: The IP is often stored in the .env file, depending on your set up. For example

`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33061`

@Krishna, your answer about where to obtain the IP seems odd because folks often use Docker _instead_ of Vagrant, AFAIK.

Also, if you're setting up as root or if you otherwise get an error message when trying to create the user because one already exists, just set up with a new user, say "workbench". (You could also edit the user's IP, e.g.).

Otherwise, this is terrific.  Thanks!

Comment: Just with 127.0.01 will work too, no need to use an IP address.

Comment: You can get the IP address by `ifconfig getifaddr en0` to get the IP address. The `docker container inspect container_name` outputs the IP address does not work for me.

Answer (score 38):

Suppose you have the next content of your `docker-compose` file:

`database:
      image: mysql:5.6
      volumes:
        - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
        - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
        - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
        - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      ports:
          - "33061:3306"`

For localhost just use host 127.0.0.1 and 33061 port
[image]

Comment: Best answer!!
You have to look at the MySQL settings in the docker-compose.yml file. Just use them

Comment: That's the right approach! I'd just advise on moving sensitive data from `environment` to an external .env file and add it in the docker-compose.yml file with `env_file: .env`

Comment: magnifique! Simple and straightforward.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Just changing the external port did the trick.

Answer (score 20):

2 docker-related conditions:

- first, your docker run must map the mysql port to an host port:

  ```
  docker run -p host:container
  ```

(for instance: `docker run -d -p 3306:3306 tutum/mysql`)

- second, if you are using docker in a VM (docker-machine, with boot2docker), you need to use the ip of `docker-machine ip <VMname>`, with the host mapped port.

  ```
  http://$(docker-machine ip <VMname>):hostPort
  ```

If you need to use `localhost`, you would need to do [some port forwarding at the VirtualBox level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707882/6309):

```
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" natpf1 "tcp-port3306,tcp,,3306,,3306"
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" natpf1 "udp-port3306,udp,,3306,,$3306"
```

(`controlvm` if the VM is running, `modifyvm` is the VM is stopped)
(replace "`boot2docker-vm`" by the name of your vm: see `docker-machine ls`)

---

2 mysql-related conditions:

- As illustrated in [`nkratzke/EasyMySQL/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/nkratzke/EasyMySQL/blob/fd7cba888ef69269d0ea313ee0a82ffa9e1a36f3/Dockerfile#L14), you need to enable remote access:

  ```
  # Enable remote access (default is localhost only, we change this
  # otherwise our database would not be reachable from outside the container)
  RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  ```
- You need to create users when startig your database in your docker image.
  See for instance [`nkratzke/EasyMySQL/start-database.sh`](https://github.com/nkratzke/EasyMySQL/blob/fd7cba888ef69269d0ea313ee0a82ffa9e1a36f3/start-database.sh#L25-L31), which is called by the [`Dockerfile CMD`](https://github.com/nkratzke/EasyMySQL/blob/fd7cba888ef69269d0ea313ee0a82ffa9e1a36f3/Dockerfile#L31):

  ```
  /usr/sbin/mysqld &
  sleep 5
  echo "Creating user"
  echo "CREATE USER '$user' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
  echo "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '$user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
  echo "GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO '$user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
  echo "finished"
  ```

Comment: Docker is running on my local machine. and it has 172.17.42.1 IP address. When I run $select user(); It gives
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) and show variable gives port                                                   | 3306

Comment: @PawanSharma are you on Linux? If yes, what was the `docker run` exact command you use to start your containerized mysql? What version of docker are you using?

Comment: Yes I am on Ubuntu mchine nad docker version is Docker version 1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3. I am able to access mysql inside docker container.

Comment: @PawanSharma OK. what was the docker run exact command you use to start your containerized mysql?

Comment: We are using docker container for multiple tools so we created a container with multiconfig files here we use command docker run -v "$XYZPATH":/apps/src/external:ro -t -i $EXPOSE_PORTS $DOCKER_REGISTRY/xxxxx:latest "$@

Comment: @PawanSharma I do not see `-p x:y` port mapping there. Plus, I have edited the answer to illustrate that your mysql image must be well configured to authorized remote access (allowing mysql workbench to contact it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95704/discussion-between-pawan-sharma-and-vonc).

Comment: EXPOSE_PORTS has this -p 3306:3306

Comment: Can you explain this? https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/274#issuecomment-650040320     
I used my ipv4 address with port 33060 , it didnt allow me , but when I created new container with -p 3306:3306 I was able to connect.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji Only a published port would be accessible/visible from host: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to connect from `Mysql Workbench` but it wasn't allowing me. Turned out, I forgot to mention the `port`. Here is the complete command to run and then connect from workbench:

## Step 1 - Run docker container:

```
docker run --name mysql8 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb -e MYSQL_USER=admin -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0.20
```

**Explanation of the above command:**

- Mysql v8.0.20 (the image name)

  ```
  mysql:8.0.20
  ```
- Run as a detached container (ctrl + c won't stop the container)

  ```
  -d
  ```
- Container name

  ```
  --name mysql8
  ```
- Port expose `(external port on host machine : internal port of the container)`

  ```
  -p 3306:3306
  ```
- Set environment variables

  ```
   -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
   -e MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
   -e MYSQL_USER=admin
   -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  ```

You can see live logs of the container by `-f means follow`:

```
docker logs mysql8 -f
```

## Step 2 - Connect from Mysql Workbench:

```
host: localhost
port: 3306
user: admin
password: root
```

Comment: This container exits immediately

Comment: @MurtazaHaji Maybe the port isn't available, or any other issue. Check the logs `docker logs mysql8 -f`

Comment: `ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add a new user with the same name, while it already exists. Destroy your existing container, and create a fresh one using the commands mentioned in my answer. **Note: You will lose all the data you have in the container if you don't know the external volume address**.

Answer (score 5):

I found a video that showed another way to get this to work.  You can specify the IP address when passing in the port number.  That is, something like `-p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306` instead of just `-p 3307:3306`  I've never seen that before
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20om-9Gwuc0#t=7m

Example start command

```
docker run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test --name mysql8 -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 mysql:8
```

Then I was able to use MYSQL Workbench to connect to `127.0.0.1` at port `3307`.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Specify your configuration `docker-compose.yml`. More details [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). Example:

   ```
   version: '3.1'

   services:
     mysql:
       image: mysql:5.6
       container_name: test-mysql
       ports:
         - 3306:3306
       restart: always
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
   ```
2. Run this comands`docker-compose up` and another terminal run `docker ps` to see your container.
3. Access your docker: `docker exec -it test-mysql bash`
4. Inside the container, to connect to mysql command line type,run `mysql -u root -p`.
5. [Create a new user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html)
6. Finally config your MySQL Workbench

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@Krishna's answer worked but with a minor change - user was added as follows

```
create user 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass';
```

see [Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this by setting field value in ***Hostname: 127.0.0.1*** (Localhost), port by default 3306 with your creds.

Comment: Which field are you referring to here?

Comment: @VonC Here i am referring workbench fields like *hostname*, *port*, *username* and *password* required for connecting mysql server.

Comment: The explain of this reason on https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

On my case, I just needed to expose the port

```
docker run -p 33061:3306 <rest of command>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions shown in mysql docker hub.
wrote this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Go to mysql workbench when you are making connection make sure to clear password in the parameters. now enter password(in my case `example`)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go in `Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding` and configure:

`Host/Guest IP` to `0.0.0.0`

`Host/Guest Port` to `3306`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it downloading the last version of MySQL Workbench, then I used host `0.0.0.0` with port `3306`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to `docker describe` the mysql container, which held its IP address. I entered that in the Workbench connection screen, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

turn off SSL connection .
where is -
use SSL .
select - NO