# Unable to connect to mongodb in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, connection

Getting connection refused when trying to connect to MongoDb in Docker container.

1. Here's the output of docker ps:

> docker ps CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>   NAMES 21063296d7d8        mongo               "/entrypoint.sh mongo"
>   44 minutes ago      Up 29 minutes       0.0.0.0:57017->27017/tcp
>   mongodb-dev

2. Here's the snippet of docker logs mongodb-dev:

> 2015-11-28T05:36:36.363+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.0.7 2015-11-28T05:36:36.363+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git
>   version: 6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd
>   2015-11-28T05:36:36.363+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info:
>   Linux ip-10-183-78-195 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64
>   BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49 2015-11-28T05:36:36.363+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc 2015-11-28T05:36:36.363+0000 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {} 2015-11-28T05:36:36.365+0000 I
>   NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

3. Here's the error when connecting to MongoDB in docker using port 57017

> mongo localhost:57017
>
> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7 connecting to: localhost:57017/test
>   2015-11-27T22:09:22.733-0800 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:57017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused 2015-11-27T22:09:22.734-0800 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to
>   server localhost:57017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181 exception: connect failed

Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you are using docker directly on a Linux host or on a Mac.
In the latter case, you would need to make sure you have port forwarded 57017 in your VirtualBox connection settings, as I mention in "[How to connect mysql workbench to running mysql inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33827463/6309)"

```
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port57017 ,tcp,,57017,,57017"
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "udp-port57017 ,udp,,57017,,57017"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After setting the port forwarding in the VirtualBox, I'm able to connect.