# Connecting to MySQL container from Mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, docker

I built a MySQL container from an image, found its IP address but unable to connect from command line or mysqlworkbench. Here's my configuration.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=test
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

COPY ./schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**Command**

```
docker build -t mysql-image .
&& docker run
-p 6603:3306
--name mysql-container
mysql-image
```

I can see that the container is running from `docker container ls`. I found its IP address using this command with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host).

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mysql-container
```

It gave me this ip -> 172.17.0.2

**Error**

[image]

**Edit**

The linked duplicate tag isn't the solution, the problem lies with the following command that misled me.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mysql-container
```

Comment: Does your phpmyadmin works? check it on http://localhost:yourMySQLportNumber/

Comment: I don't have phpmyadmin, my env is nodejs

Comment: yes localhost worked, actually 127.0.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect mysql workbench to running mysql inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827342/how-to-connect-mysql-workbench-to-running-mysql-inside-docker)

Comment: I think you'll need phpmysql to see mysql interface... if not, then check your mysql port number(default is 3306) so in your case, try  127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: I used `127.0.0.1:6603` instead of `172.17.0.2:6603` and it worked, The linked answer to find ip address of db actually misled me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `localhost` (127.0.0.1) instead the container IP (in your case 172.17.0.2) at `hostname`

Comment: why is that, the tutorial i followed used 172 as the ip and it worked for him but for me 127 worked, wondering why? and what should i put in the production code for db connection?

Comment: Here you have some explanation about that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach (at the end of the answer)

Comment: so basically 127 is host mode and 172 is bridge mode?

Comment: Something like that, I'm not an expert in docker yet and I cant say yes but its seems like that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the allow login from any ip with **MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%**

Full docker command line as follows:

```
>docker run --name mysql-server -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql/mysql-server
```

> --name means that it's container name
>
> -d means that docker will run in deattach mode. Final it's mysql docker image

When docker status is  **Up 3 minutes (healthy)** you can easy connect to DB via mysql Workbench

[image]

Hope to help you!