# How to connect MySQL with Docker using Navicat or MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench, navicat

I am using the MySQL Docker images, and I can connect to this Docker with `mysqli_connect('mysql', 'docker', 'docker');` in php

Here is `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
c271f8e68378        afraidjpg/nginx:nginx   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10086->10086/tcp   nginx
92d7c923f777        afraidjpg/php:php56     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                         php
68b818bd68c4        afraidjpg/mysql:mysql   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp              mysql
```

I use `--link mysql` option when starting PHP Docker.

IP of MySQL Docker is **172.17.0.2**.

My mac's IP is **192.168.1.50**

**here is user in mysql:**

```
mysql> select User, Host from mysql.user;
+--------+-----------+
| User   | Host      |
+--------+-----------+
| docker | %         |
| root   | localhost |
+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

then I tried to connect mysql with navicat and mysql-workbench

host:192.168.1.50, user:docker, pass:docker `Access denied for user 'docker'@'%%' (using password: YES)`

host:127.0.0.1, user:docker, pass:docker `Access denied for user 'docker'@'%%' (using password: YES)`

host:172.17.0.2, user:docker, pass:docker `Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2`

all get the error with `Access denied for user 'docker'@'%%' (using password: YES)`

if l tried to change user from ***docker*** to ***root***, error become `Access denied for user 'docker'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)`

I found some article before, and followed their step, but always failed. I don't where I was wrong

**here are some screenshot**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**update**
I cannot ping from local to docker, and there is no ping command in docker so I cannot do the test to ping from docker to local

```
zk ~/Documents/PHP/www/docker $ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

**more update**

I can connect to mysql with command in terminal with `mysql -udocker -p --portocol=tcp`

**more details**

error message is `Access denied for user 'docker'@'%%' (using password: YES)`, It `said @'%%'`, I know what the '%' is, but what's mean of '%%'?

Comment: You can install a ping command if you wish.

Comment: If you're getting "access denied", you're connecting successfully but don't have an acceptable username/password/source.  The `docker inspect` IP address is unreachable from a MacOS host, and you don't need to look it up on any platform.

Comment: were you able to login to mysql container and login to mysql?

Comment: ?@DavidMaze So how can l login successful? I can login with terminal by specify `--portocol` option, but cannot connect by navicat or mysql-workbench

Comment: @Ntwobike I can login by terminal, login in the docker, login by php script. but just cannot login by any GUI tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do try host as `mysql` instead of localhost from the connected container. If you are on windows try `192.168.99.100` as host.

If still having issue try retest with **mysql-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    command: "--innodb_use_native_aio=0"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /var/database/docker/common:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mysqlnet
      - mysqlnetfpm

networks:
  mysqlnet:
    driver: bridge
  mysqlnetfpm:
    driver: bridge
```

***Note: Before running new mysql container don't forgot to delete the older mysqldata files.***

Now you can use the username as `root`, password as `root` and for the internal containers(attached containers) use the host as mysql.

If you are try to connect from outside the docker do try with host as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or your public `docker ip`.

Comment: hostname with mysql: Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (0), l am running on MacOS, So my docker ip is 172.17.0.2

Comment: Are you still getting issue with try this `192.168.1.50`

Comment: yes, tried this ip with user 'docker' and root, all failed. my local machine's mysql server has been stopped. Now the running server of mysql is only the mysql8.0 in docker

Comment: Try run this docker-compose file.. it's for mysql 5.7 https://gist.github.com/vikash-aika/2aae0b23cde9884291088faf341891f9

Comment: Now just try using `root` as password along with your docker ip or `127.0.0.1` as host. also make sure the given path for database root in docker-compose is correct as per your environment.

Comment: still didn't word

Comment: l delete the mysqldata then restart docker images. It works, So, finally It may be may fault(even I don't know what's happened), But still thank you for your docker-compose file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194153/discussion-between-vikash-pathak-and-afraid-jpg).

Comment: Hi, please see this answer in link below, I think that help you with this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431294/1939983

Thanks,