# Is it possible to see my WordPress database in MySQL workbench when developing locally and using Docker?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, docker

I have a docker-compose file that I am using for creating a WordPress environment and it works as expected. I did the docker-compose up and here are my containers:
[my containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUGTy.png)

and more info about my MySQL container:
[MySQL container more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWQY0.png)

and my docker-compose content:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

My question is, how can I possibly see the database in the MySQL workbench application? More precisely which port and hostname and connection type should I use here? I tried everything and couldn't see my db:
[MySQL workbench config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzAzF.png)

Comment: you need a similiar construct for mysql as for wrdpress https://stackoverflow.com/a/41431772/5193536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate ( [How to connect mysql workbench to running mysql inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827342/how-to-connect-mysql-workbench-to-running-mysql-inside-docker) )

Have you tried:

```
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

or

```
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I actually tried 127.0.0.1 and db for my hostname with port 3306 and it did not work. The question is not duplicate, I have docker and MySQL working as expected, I need to setup workbench to see my db in there.

Comment: Check the link, how is your scenario different to the answer suggested in there. Have you created a new mysql user for workbench to connect with?

Comment: hey Ryan, sorry for my late reply, I tried that link and you were right, that was sort of duplicate question, I tried all the steps in there but when I want to create the user it fails. Anyways I resolved the problem in another way, I added these lines to my docker file:
```
  phpmyadmin: 
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80``` 
and now using phpMyAdmin plugin on localhost:8081 to see the database.